# How do I automatically get the "Automatic alias" option checked for the content type?

Tags: path-aliases

I have the Pathauto module, and I want to have the 'Automatic alias' checkbox selected by default for the new content types I create.

Is there a way to obtain this?

Answer (score 2):

After you define the pattern of the content type path, it will be checked automatically when you add the node of that content type.

The path is admin/config/search/path/patterns.

Comment: as i have a multilanguage site, instead of setting a single pattern for each language, i set the pattern for *italian* Pages, and leaved blank the pattern of *english* pages because i set the 'Default path pattern for Page (applies to all Pagina base content types with blank patterns below)' - so i think this should cause every page in any language to have that checkbox checked by default.

this could be a bug?